# How to figure out dimensions of image to use from Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, image-scaling

I have a `UIImageView` in a screen in my Storyboard. From the Dimensions of the image in the Storyboard, what size image should I exporting from my photo editor (like Illustrator) so that the image does not look bad / stretch / out of proportion?

*iOS Noob here* -- trying to figure out what dimensions of the image to request from my designer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the imageView is constrained so its size never changes, you can just find the size of the view in the size inspector and use that. If the imageView or image shape might change, you can set the imageView to Aspect Fit or apply constraints that allow different aspect ratios.